# Idris implicits error message "... is not an implicit argument of ..."

Tags: idris

I have the following interface definition in file *A*:

```
interface Loader (c : Type -> Type) r where
  LoadType : Type
  idToFilepath : (id : String) -> String
  loadFilepath : (x : Var) -> (filepath : String) -> ST c r [x ::: LoadType]

  load : (x : Var) -> (id : String) -> ST c r [x ::: LoadType]
  load {c} {r} x id = loadFilepath x (idToFilepath {c} {r} id)
```

If I remove `{c} {r}` from the definition of `load` and the call to `idToFilepath`, it won't typecheck, giving the following message:

```
Can't find implementation for Loader c r
```

Otherwise, file *A* typechecks. This is weird, but I've seen that passing implicits around explicitly can sometimes help.

The issue is in an attempted implementation of this interface, in file *B*. Even though the definition of the `Loader` interface in file *A* typechecks, as soon as a minimal implementation is attempted in file *B*, it does not typecheck. Here is the code for reference:

```
interface Draw (m : Type -> Type) where 
  -- ...

Draw m => Loader m Texture where
  LoadType {m} = ?check
```

It gives the following weird error message:

```
When checking left hand side of Resources.Main.m, Texture implementation of Resources.Loader, method load:
c is not an implicit argument of Resources.Main.m, Texture implementation of Resources.Loader, method load
```

Which makes no sense given that file *A* typechecked and no substantive code has been introduced in *B*.